# Android SearchView Action Bar

Tags: android

I want to add search on action bar but  it doesn't  work correctly. I put my code below:

Menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

this is code for `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_options, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = 
            (SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search));
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    return true;
}
```

res/xml/searchable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

layout `activity_search_result.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textViewSearchResult"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My `Activity`

```
public class SearchResultActivity extends Activity {
    TextView mTextViewSearchResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);
    mTextViewSearchResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewSearchResult);
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
         handleSearch(getIntent().getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY));
       }
    }

    private void handleSearch(String searchQuery) {
        mTextViewSearchResult.setText(searchQuery);
    }
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *"it doesn't work correctly"*

Comment: SearchResultActivity does't work the result just show the search in action bar nothing happend

Comment: what are you trying to search for? Where is the data? ... Look at this example, maybe it help you http://www.javarticles.com/2015/07/android-search-widget-example.html